# Is there an HTML5 version/equivalent of Uploadify (the jQuery plugin)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, html

Ideally, would like to be able to easily do drag and dropping of files to be uploaded.

If so, where can I find it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as far as I know, but the standard is still fairly young. There's a great little HTML 5 feature reference at http://slides.html5rocks.com/#landing-slide (updated link as of 24/May/2013)

Keep in mind they're also updating a JavaScript along with the HTML 5 standard so it may become inbuilt.

Hope this helps,

Jace

Comment: I do want that functionality, but in a jQuery plugin - rather than having to de-construct that functionality and implementing it manually. I might end up having to do that, but just wondering if something already exists like that.

Answer (score 7):

I think  PLUpload http://www.plupload.com/ is pretty much what you want. It supports HTML5, Flash, Silverlight, Gears, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of anybody stumbling on this question in the current day, Uploadify (the plugin mentioned by the OP) is actually available in a HTML5 variant, though there is a perfectly reasonable $5 price tag for it.  The Flash-based version is still free.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I can tell from looking at the Uploadify website, the script provides a way to upload multiple files with a single input.

I don't know about HTML 5 off the top of my head, but an HTML 4 file input allows multiple files to be uploaded.

> This control type allows the user to select **files** so that their contents may be submitted with a form.

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#file-select

> If multiple files are to be returned as the result of a single form entry,

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

Browser support is, however, rather weak. I think I remember hearing that Opera implemented it a while back.

Comment: What I was really looking for is a plugin taking advantage of the drag & drop functionality from the HTML5 spec.